# listViewItem.setOnItemClickListener not wroking

Tags: android, listview

I used `setOnitemclicklistener` for custom `ListView` using adapter, but it not working, please help me. Here is HomeActivity:

```
 public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
TabHost tabHosts;
public ListView listView;
private Context ctx;
private ListView listViewItem;
TextView ime;
ImageView imgAppLable;
public String text = "";
TelephonyManager manager;
int ArrNameLable[] = {};
Button btnClick;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  // setActionBar(toolbar);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //get imei
    manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    ime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewImei);
    text = manager.getDeviceId().toString();
    ime.setText("Your imei:  " + text);
    //Tab host
    TabHost host = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    host.setup();
    Resources res = getResources();
    //Tab 1
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Offers");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Offers");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 2
    spec = host.newTabSpec("Share");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Share");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 3
    spec = host.newTabSpec("My Earnings");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec.setIndicator("My Earnings");
    host.addTab(spec);

    // ListVIew Item

    ctx = this;
    List<MoveData> legendList = new ArrayList<MoveData>();
    legendList.add(new MoveData("AppName", "100", "icon_dollar"));
    legendList.add(new MoveData("AppName", "150", "icon_home"));
    legendList.add(new MoveData("AppName", "200", "icon_dollar"));
    legendList.add(new MoveData("AppName", "250", "icon_home"));
    legendList.add(new MoveData("AppName", "300", "icon_dollar"));
    legendList.add(new MoveData("AppName", "350", "icon_home"));

    listViewItem = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItem);
    listViewItem.setAdapter(new AdapterCustomListview(ctx, R.layout.custom_layout_single, legendList));

    // Click event for single list row

    listViewItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position + "is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


           // String o = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
           // Toast.makeText(Home.this, o, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Here is MoveData:

```
 public class MoveData {


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCoin() {
    return coin;
}

public void setCoin(String coin) {
    this.coin = coin;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

private String name;
private String coin;
private String image;

public MoveData(String AppName, String Coin, String image) {
    super();
    this.name = AppName;
    this.coin = Coin;
    this.image = image;

}
}
```

Here is CustomLisviewDataAdapter:

```
public class AdapterCustomListview extends ArrayAdapter<MoveData> {
private int resource;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

public AdapterCustomListview(Context ctx, int resourceId, List<MoveData> objects) {
    super(ctx, resourceId, objects);
    resource = resourceId;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    MoveData Legend = getItem(position);
    TextView legendName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAppName);
    legendName.setText(Legend.getName());

    TextView legendBorn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCoin);
    legendBorn.setText(Legend.getCoin());

    ImageView legendImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgApps);
    String uri = "drawable/" + Legend.getImage();
    int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
    //noinspection deprecation

    Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageResource);
    legendImage.setImageDrawable(image);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: what was the problem on Click..?

Comment: Yep, i was set action for onItemClickListener but it not working, nothing to show when i click in list view. Can u help me? 


 listViewItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position + "is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get click events by modifying getView() method inside adapter as below :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    MoveData Legend = getItem(position);
    TextView legendName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAppName);
    legendName.setText(Legend.getName());

    TextView legendBorn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCoin);
    legendBorn.setText(Legend.getCoin());

    ImageView legendImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgApps);
    String uri = "drawable/" + Legend.getImage();
    int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
    //noinspection deprecation

    Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageResource);
    legendImage.setImageDrawable(image);

convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position + "is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});


    return convertView;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, u r god of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any problem with your onItemClickListener it should works fine but you should modify your Toast like below lines because you want to show the position in toast but position is in int so either firstly you have to change the position into string or you may write any string just for testing purpose:-

```
Toast.makeText(Home.this, "o", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thank for reviews my problem, i did it. :3

Comment: sloved. :D i was set on click listener inside adapter.